# Checking if a class is java.lang.Enum

Tags: java, enums, instanceof

I'm trying to know if a class is an Enum, but I think I'm missing something:

```
if (test.MyEnum.class instanceof Enum<?>.class)
 obj = resultWrapper.getEnum(i, test.MyEnum.class);
else 
 obj = resultWrapper.getObject(i);
```

It gives me an error saying that Enum.class is not valid. So how I can check if a class is a Enum? I'm pretty sure it is possible to determine that, I'm just unable to get it.

Thanks

Answer (score 166, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(test.MyEnum.class)
```

but for enums, here is a more convenient method:

```
if (someObject.getClass().isEnum()))
```

---

Update: for enum items with a body (e. g. that override methods), this won't actually work.
In that case, use

```
if (someObject instanceof Enum<?>)
```

**Reference:**

- [`Class.isEnum()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isEnum%28%29)

Comment: Beware of `isEnum()`. It returns false if your class is an anonymous class created by one of the enum values overriding a method.

Comment: @Trejkaz could you elaborate on that? I'm not quite following you

Comment: If you have methods in your enum, individual values of the enum can override them. If you override any of these methods it creates an anonymous class which is a subclass of the enum. isEnum() for that class returns false. Thus, even though EnumClass.class.isEnum() returns true, EnumClass.SOME_VALUE.getClass().isEnum() might return false, so you have to be careful about where you get the class from. For instance, if you were writing a utility method for others to call, using isEnum() would be a bad idea and using Enum.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) would be safer.

Comment: @Trejkaz I see, in that case, getDeclaringClass() would be the correct way to do it. will update my answer. thanks!

Comment: In some cases someObject.getClass().isEnum() doesn't work as expected, for example what happens if enum implements an interface? (I am getting false)....

Comment: @Paolo implementing interfaces doesn't make a difference as you can see here: https://ideone.com/2GrfJb , but it does make a difference whether the enum item has a body, in which case you have to consult the enclosing class (and not the declaring class as I have written above). So your only safe bet for all cases is `someObject instanceof Enum<?>` :-(

Comment: `someObject.getClass().getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class` would also work and especially useful if you only have a Class: `someClass.getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class`

Comment: @Benny Bottema "someObject.getClass().getSuperclass() == java.lang.Enum.class" is false if someObject is an enum constant with a body . It will then return you the class of the enum type itself, e.g. "TimeUnit.DAYS.getClass().getSuperclass() == java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.class". You can use that to find out whether two enum constants with bodies are constants of the same enum.

Answer (score 14):

If you're talking about Java 5 new feature - `enum`  (it's not very new actually), then this is the way to go:

```
if (obj.getClass().isEnum()) {

...
}
```

If `Enum` is your custom class, then just check that `obj instanceof Enum`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for: TimeUnit.SECONDS.getClass().isEnum()