# How to load a .kt file from src folder?

Tags: android, kotlin

Within the same project I am trying to get all the files that contain `enum`. I don't know the file names that contain this.

I normally could do: `.getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");`

but in this case I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at runtime, on the phone? If so, your Kotlin source code usually is not packaged in the APK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way you can get the classes inside your application. [Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection/22462785)

It requires this library https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Once you get all classes
you can iterate through all of them and use this solution.
[Checking if a class is java.lang.Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166488/checking-if-a-class-is-java-lang-enum)

There are a few caveats when trying to figure out if a class is truly an enum depending on where it exists. The accepted answer has 3 solutions to deal with the caveats.

Note this is in `Java` but should be easily convertible.